# How to exclude null values in table calculation in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to present a cohort analysis in Tableau. The dimensions are the first month a visitor arrived and the age of a cohort, and the measure is the number of visitors. I'd like to show the percentage retained from the first month of each cohort over each cohort. My problem is that when I do a table calculation to calculate the percent difference Tableau treats null values as 0, so it incorrectly shows -100% loss for the lower half of the table.

So for example this:

```
     | 0   | 1    | 2  

May  | 100 | 90   | 80 

June | 200 | 170  | null

July | 300 | null | null
```

Turns into this when I do a percentage difference table calculation with respect to the first value in each row:

```
     | 0   | 1    | 2  

May  | 0%  | -10%   | -20% 

June | 0%  | -30%   | -100%

July | 0%  | -100%  | -100%
```

But I would expect that all the cells with `-100%` should actually be null.

Is there a way to make Tableau correctly deal with the null values so that nothing is displayed in the lower half of the table instead of `-100%`?

Comment: You can do something like IF ISNULL([field]) THEN..., share us your current code so we can help you

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just checked the code for value I'm computing and this is what it looks like: (ZN(SUM([Count])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Count])), FIRST())) / ABS(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Count])), FIRST())) I just removed the ZN functions and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Easier than IF/ELSEs, if you're comfortable with null results. Great you could figure it out!